# high performance several horizontal collection views in table view cells with RxSwift/RxDataSources

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

A famous layout you can find in most apps is having several horizontal lists in a table view cell where each list gets its data from the server. can be found in Airbnb.  example below:

Each list has a loading view and an empty state to show when something is wrong.

Each list triggers the network request only when its first time created, so when displayed again by scrolling the table view, it should NOT make another network request to get data.

I tried several approaches and but not yet satisfied. some of which run into memory leaks and performance issues when having several collectionview. currently, I do the network requests in the View controller that holds the table view and passes the data to each cell.

Can anyone share their approach on how to do this? Appreciated!
Example:

[image]

Comment: You can try offline caching mechanism. So that you can show the cached data while scrolling as well perform a network call in background and sync with the offline data. Update the view if its still available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a huge question with a lot of different possible answers. I recently solved it by using a custom table view data source that reports the first time (and only the first time) an item is displayed by a cell. I used that to trigger when the individual inner network requests should happen. It uses the `.distinct()` operator which is implemented in RxSwiftExt...

```
final class CellReportingDataSource<Element>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, RxTableViewDataSourceType where Element: Hashable {

    let cellCreated: Observable<Element>

    init(createCell: @escaping (UITableView, IndexPath, Element) -> UITableViewCell) {
        self.createCell = createCell
        cellCreated = _cellCreated.distinct()
        super.init()
    }

    deinit {
        _cellCreated.onCompleted()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, observedEvent: Event<[Element]>) {
        if case let .next(sections) = observedEvent {
            self.items = sections
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = createCell(tableView, indexPath, item)
        _cellCreated.onNext(item)
        return cell
    }

    private var items: [Element] = []
    private let createCell: (UITableView, IndexPath, Element) -> UITableViewCell
    private let _cellCreated = PublishSubject<Element>()
}
```

Each table view cell needs its own Observable that emits the results of the network call every time something subscribes to it. I do that by using `.scan(into:accumulator:)`. An example might be something like this:

```
dataSource.cellCreated
    .map { ($0, /* logic to convert a table view item into network call parameters */) }
    .flatMap {
        Observable.zip(
            Observable.just($0.0),
            networkCall($0.1)
                .map { Result.success($0) }
                .catchError { Result.failure($0) }
        )
    }
    .scan(into: [TableViewItem: Result<NetworkResponse, Error>]()) { current, next in
        current[next.0] = next.1
    }
    .share(replay: 1)
```

Each cell can subscribe to the above and use `compactMap` to extract it's particular piece of state.